# Second JFrame icon in Windows Taskbar is created when the program is runned

Tags: java, jframe, taskbar

I wrote a small program using a `JFrame`. I exported the program with Eclipse and created a shortcut for it which I then pinned to the windows task bar. When I run the program, rather than stacking over the pinned item, a new item is created on the task bar for the running program. How would I fix this?

Comment: Java doesn't support stacking by default, this is a OS specific feature.  There is a (paid) library which can achieve this

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hmm, alright then :/